# Loading embeded youtube video via link

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, embed

I am having trouble with chrome. The code below works fine in safari but when I click it in chrome the screen goes white. Any thoughts?

```
      <div class="CollapsiblePanelContent" style="text-align:center"><div style="padding:15px;">
      <!--youtube-->
      <?php
      $url = http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J57IcTH0DQs;
        preg_match('/[\\?\\&]v=([^\\?\\&]+)/', $url, $matches);
        $id = $matches[1];

        $width = '480';
        $height = '270';
        echo '<object width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/' .   
        $id . '?version=3&autoplay=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param 
        name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/' . $id . 
        '?version=3&autoplay=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" 
        width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '"></embed></object>';

    ?>
</div>

      </div>
```

Comment: If this is really a browser issue, please post html from source instead of php

Comment: I mean, if this is a browser issue, then your server side code is irrelevant. It would be much easier to see what's going on if you would show the output the server delivers, i.e. what the browser is seeing. just right click on the page, click view source, and post the relevant html.

Comment: I posted one of the links that is pulled from the server.

Comment: If you want me to try and help you, please post pure HTML only. Without any php.

Comment: Alsok, the <param> and <embed> tags don't need closing tags (</param>). Maybe this is whats messing with chrome